# Angular routing: parameter in middle of string or after prefix

Tags: angular, angular-routing, url-parameters

Using Angular 9 with its build-in routing, I'd have the route definition below:

```
{ path: '/mysubfolder/:param', component: MyAwesomeComponent },
```

The parameter has always the form 'foo_123'. 'foo_' is a hardcoded constant which never changes. In the component, I then split by '_', process '123' further and forget about 'foo_'.

That works pretty well. The problem is: There should be an error page that handles all non-existent pages. It is defined like so

```
{ path: '**', pathMatch: 'full', component: ErrorPageComponent }
```

That also works for vanilla URLs like '/barbarbar'. However, for '/mysubfolder/blablabla', it doesn't work. Of course, I'll get to `MyAwesomeComponent` instead of the error page (which is not what I want here).

So, since `param` always starts with 'foo_', I'd like to define something like

```
{ path: '/mysubfolder/foo_:param', component: MyAwesomeComponent },
```

in the routing. But that doesn't work. Is this not possible at all in Angular 9 or do I do something wrong here? Is there an alternative for solving that problem? (Requirement is: URL may not change, so '/mysubfolder/foo/:param' is not an option.)

Of course, I could redirect within MyAwesomeComponent all requests with a parameter that does not start with 'foo' to the error page. But that seems ugly and hacky. And it will not work if in the future, I add more cases like this.

Comment: what do you do when the id does not exist? like foo_666 and 666 is not a valid id?

Comment: @Markus Dresch That's handled inside the component and not a problem.

Comment: then handling an invalid prefix inside the component would be consistent and not hacky in my view. i don't know of a way to make routes work the way you want though.

Comment: @Markus Dresch It will not work anymore if in the future, if I want in addition to '/foo_123' going to `MyAwesomeCompnent` add the route '/bar_acd' going to `AnotherComponent` and n other cases like this. Then I would have to redirect from `MyAwesomeCompnent` to `AnotherComponent` and from there to N other cases etc. And that is really hacky and ugly.

Comment: Can you use CanActivate https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate to check the validity of the id and route accordingly?

Comment: is there a reason for using mysubfolder/foo_:param instead of mysubfolder/foo/param. ?

Comment: @Vinaayakh There is more a less a reason, but not a technical one.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an auth guard

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()

export class RouteGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const encryptedParams = next.params.id
    if(<check condition>){
      // proceed to the component
      return true
    }else{
      this.router.navigate(['/error']);
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

and add it to the route

```
{ path: '/mysubfolder/:param', component: MyAwesomeComponent, canActivate:[RouteGuard] },
```

The auth guard will perform the checks before the MyAwesomeComponent is loaded and you can add additional checks to it later on as required.